# Lock the phone using Flex 4 application

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flex4

Currently I am working on a mobile based application using Flex 4 and action script 3. Normally for locking android phones, we need to press the lock button, but I want to lock the android phone by application.

Is there any API available for this? I need to lock the phone by running the application, which is created using Flex 4 and action script 3. Please give me some idea for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Flex 4 is little difficult. better you can try with native android application. There are some options are available, like

```
KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

and another way is `android.os.PowerManager`

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
//and use 
wl.release();
```

The detail description about `PowerManager` you can find from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether locking the device pro grammatically is still possible with Android, but you may follow this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793339/lock-an-android-phone) for the latest.

AIR does not provide API to lock a mobile device, because such capability is not universally available on all mobile/desktop platforms.  AIR's design philosophy is to keep its default SDK features to be available to all platforms, so developers don't have to think of platforms' discrepancies.

The latest AIR provides the means to extend platform-specific capability through [Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html) (ANE).  You can check variety of extensions over numerous sites such as [this one](http://extensionsforair.com/).

That said, if Android natively provides locking capability, you are in good luck.  Even if such ANE is not available, I am sure you can easily get one developed.

Comment: Through the ANE ,it's very difficult to achieve this. it's better we can call PowerManager for this kind Device Admin tasks.